# Add page reference to either one entry of a pair of synonyms in the glossary

Tags: glossaries

A have a glossary that contains a lot of entries that are synomyms. In the glossary's definition I chosed one of them to be the "main" entry that also has a short definition of the term. All other terms just print a "see" and forward to the main entry.

In my running text I would like to use all synonyms equally due to stylistic reasons. But this means that the page references are scattered to all the entries in the glossary. What I really would like to have is that the page reference is added to the main entry even if one of
the synomyms is cited.

How is the done best?

This is my solution so far. In the glossary's definition I have

```
\longnewglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={foo}%
}{%
  Explanation of foo. Another term is \glshyperlink{bar}.%
}

\longnewglossaryentry{bar}{%
  name={bar}%
}{%
  See \glshyperlink{foo}%
}
```

Here "foo" is the main entry and "bar" is the synonym. Now, if I use `\gls{foo}` and `\gls{bar}` in my running text, some page numbers are added under "foo" and some under "bar". In case of "foo" this is correct, but the page numbers of "bar" shall appear at "foo", too.

Of course, I can use something like

```
\glslink[]{foo}{\glsentrytext{bar}}
\glsentrytext{bar}\glsadd{foo}
```

whenever I want a page number added to "foo" but print "bar". But this approach has two major drawbacks

1. It is very error-prone. Whenever I want to use "bar", I must remember to actually link to "foo". And I have a lot of these pairs.
2. The "first-use"-flag is not queried.

Any better ideas?